# Oracle Apex dynamic action PL/SQL that will change the values in a select list based on a value passed by another field

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

So i have a Table Called "Fruit" this table is manually upload with what kind of Fruit the users like. But we know that we have different colored "Fruit" these colors are not on the table.

So i have created a form for the user and want to create a dynamic select list based on the "Fruit"

Form:

Name: Bob

Age:  45

Fruit: Apple

What color:(Select List based of Fruit) *Red,Green,white*

Now i have 12 fruit option on the table and maybe six color i want to use, but i do not want all the colors displayed.

So if the "Fruit" column (based on table) was apple only show *Red,Green,white* in the select list

if the "Fruit" column (based on table) was banana only show *Yellow,Green,Brown* in the select list

if the "Fruit" column (based on table) was grape only show *Red,Green* in the select list.

Answer (score 2):

APEX can do this quite easily.  Define the query for the colors so that it only shows the colors appropriate for the fruit item selected.  Something like:

```
select c.color_name, c.color_code
  from colors c
       join fruit_colors fc on fc.color_code = c.color_code
 where fc.fruit_code = :P123_FRUIT_CODE;
```

(Here `P123_FRUIT_CODE` is the name of your fruit select list item).

Then set the `Cascading LOV Parent Item(s)` property of the colors LOV to `P123_FRUIT_CODE`.

Now, whenever the user changes `P123_FRUIT_CODE` by selecting a fruit, the colors LOV will be updated to show only the colors available for that fruit.

Comment: Hi Tony, would that mean i would need to create a color table as well then?

Comment: Not necessarily, that was just my assumption.  You just need to write the SQL that references `:P123_FRUIT_CODE` in the `where` clause and returns the colours you want it to return.